# How to configure the level of output from the maven dependency convergence plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using the maven enforcer plugin with the dependency converge in a multi module build so it runs the enfrocer plugin for every pom in the build. every time this plugin runs it produces a massive amount of info output that makes it hard to read the build result. For example in my case it is producing about 400 lines of output for each invocation of the plugin. Code below shows an example of the output.

How do I configure the enforcer dependency convergence plugin to only output violations otherwise don't print anything out other than dependency convergence check successfull?

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1.1:enforce (enforce-dependencies-convergence) @ bar ---
[INFO] com.example:bar 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] postgresql:postgresql 9.1-901-1.jdbc4 9.1-901-1.jdbc4
[INFO] com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.1.0 2.1.0
[INFO] com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations 2.1.0 2.1.0
[INFO] com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core 2.1.0 2.1.0
[INFO] javax.inject:javax.inject 1 1
[INFO] cglib:cglib-nodep 2.2.2 2.2.2
[INFO] com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-core 1.7 1.7
[INFO] joda-time:joda-time 2.1 2.1
[INFO] com.google.guava:guava 13.0.1 13.0.1
[INFO] org.hibernate:hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final 4.3.0.Final
[INFO] javax.validation:validation-api 1.0.0.GA 1.0.0.GA
[INFO] org.jsoup:jsoup 1.7.1 1.7.1
[INFO] org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient 4.2.2 4.2.2
[INFO] org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore 4.2.2 4.2.2
[INFO] commons-codec:commons-codec 1.6 1.6
[INFO] commons-io:commons-io 2.4 2.4
[INFO] commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload 1.2.2 1.2.2
[INFO] org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12 1.7.2 1.7.2
[INFO] org.slf4j:slf4j-api 1.7.2 1.7.2
[INFO] log4j:log4j 1.2.17 1.2.17
[INFO] org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j 1.7.2 1.7.2
[INFO] org.slf4j:slf4j-api 1.7.2 1.7.2
[INFO] org.slf4j:slf4j-api 1.7.2 1.7.2
[INFO] org.apache.velocity:velocity 1.7 1.7
[INFO] commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.1 3.2.1
[INFO] org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final 4.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager 4.1.8.Final 4.1.8.Final
[INFO] org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging 3.1.0.GA 3.1.0.GA
[INFO] org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec 1.0.0.Final 1.0.0.Final
[INFO] dom4j:dom4j 1.6.1 1.6.1
[INFO] org.hibernate:hibernate-core 4.1.8.Final 4.1.8.Final
[INFO] antlr:antlr 2.7.7 2.7.7
[INFO] org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging 3.1.0.GA 3.1.0.GA
[INFO] org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging 3.1.0.GA 3.1.0.GA
[INFO] org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec 1.0.0.Final 1.0.0.Final
[INFO] org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec 1.0.0.Final 1.0.0.Final
[INFO] dom4j:dom4j 1.6.1 1.6.1
[INFO] dom4j:dom4j 1.6.1 1.6.1
[INFO] org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.1.Final 1.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.javassist:javassist 3.15.0-GA 3.15.0-GA
[INFO] org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final 4.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final 4.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.1.Final 1.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.1.Final 1.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.javassist:javassist 3.15.0-GA 3.15.0-GA
[INFO] org.javassist:javassist 3.15.0-GA 3.15.0-GA
[INFO] org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final 4.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final 4.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final 4.0.1.Final
[INFO] org.aspectj:aspectjweaver 1.7.1 1.7.1
[INFO] org.aspectj:aspectjrt 1.7.1 1.7.1
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-aop 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] aopalliance:aopalliance 1.0 1.0
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-expression 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-test 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-oxm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] commons-lang:commons-lang 2.5 2.5
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-webmvc 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-asm 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context-support 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-context 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-core 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-expression 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-expression 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-web 3.1.3.RELEASE 3.1.3.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MENFORCER-135

Will be fixed in version 1.2 and current version is 1.1.1 which you are using.

You'll just have to wait for that release :-(